# Parse and Show the data of a JSON file in Scala | Meaning of .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").getOrCreate()

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new in SparkSQL, I am trying to parse and show the data of a JSON file.
So My question is I cannot understand the Line number 2 in my code given below, why the builder function is not like the Documentation(*.setAppName instead of .appName etc..*) I have mentioned given below? What does mean of this added portion- ***"some-value").getOrCreate()*** in Line number 2 of my code?
I will be thankful from the bottom of my heart if someone help me to understand this.

**employee.json**

```
{"name":"John", "age":28}
{"name":"Andrew", "age":36}
{"name":"Clarke", "age":22}
{"name":"Kevin",  "age":42}
{"name":"Richard","age":51}
```

**Code:**

```
 1. import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
 2. val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Spark SQL basic example").config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").getOrCreate()
 3. import spark.implicits._
 4. val df = spark.read.json("examples/src/main/resources/employee.json")
 5. df.show()
```

**Output:**

```
+---+-------+
|age|   name|
+---+-------+
| 28|   John|
| 36| Andrew|
| 22| Clarke|
| 42|  Kevin|
| 51|Richard|
+---+-------+
```

***=============================>>>>>>>>>>***
Please Note:

According to the Documentation of SparkConf passed to your SparkContext. SparkConf allows you to configure some of the common properties (e.g. master URL and application name), as well as arbitrary key-value pairs through the set() method. as follows::

> val conf = new
>   SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("CountingSheep")
>
> val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

Comment: Some config is only just some configuration option... Don't read it literally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See nowadays from Spark 2.0.0 , if you are using the sql part of the Spark then **SparkSession** is the de-facto standard that you need to follow to create.

```
In the Second line i.e. 
 2. val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Spark SQL basic example").config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").getOrCreate()
```

You can write this same thing using the spark conf as you used to do it earlier that you have pasted in the note :

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("CountingSheep")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Now what you can do is

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("CountingSheep")

val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate()
```

And if you want sc to be specific you can extract it from SparkSession variable itself.

```
val sc = spark.sparkContext
```

Now coming to your getOrCreate():

See we cannot have two SparkContext for the same application, same goes for the SparkSession so what getOrCreate() does is it searches if there is an already existing SparkContext or SparkSession object and if there is then just get its reference and provide it to the variable. If its not present then create one and pass it on to the variable.

P.S : I hope this explanation helps you. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it. So, if we do not import implicit package then what will go to happened?

Comment: See AFAIK , the implicits will allow you to read the json directly as a spark DataSet

Comment: K, Fine! Nice explanation

Comment: implicits would enable to create dataframes and datasets using `.toDF` and `.toDS` . Your code would have worked without importing implicits

Answer (score 0):

You code is of *spark 2.0* or newer verions but the documentation you are referring is of older versions of spark.

In 2.0 version `SparkSession` was introduced which is a combination of `SparkContext` for computing `rdds` and `SqlContext` for computing SQL queries on `dataframes`. So the api is changed.

In older versions of spark, `SparkConf` is used to set the configuration, `SparkContext` is used to set contexts for `rdds` and `SQLContext` is used to set contexts for `dataframes` and `datasets`.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("CountingSheep").set("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
```

But in newer version greater than 2.0, it is done as

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Spark SQL basic example").config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").getOrCreate()
val sc = spark.sparkContext
val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
```

Now `spark.some.config.option` and `some-value` are key value pairs of configuation properties. for example [spark configuration properties](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) and [yarn properties](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml) etc.

```
spark.some.config.option = textinputformat.record.delimiter 
some-value = ~%$
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

I try to convert a **JSON** file to a **conf** file structure using "[io.circe](https://github.com/circe/circe-config)" library.

My implementation is like:

Step: 1

.sbt file looks like:

```
organization := "com.sample.json.convert"

name := "convert-json-conf"

version := "1.0.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-feature")
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8", "-Xlint")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.0" % "provided",
 "io.circe" %% "circe-core" % "0.10.0-M2",
 "io.circe" %% "circe-parser" % "0.10.0-M2",
 "io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % "0.10.0-M2",
 "io.circe" %% "circe-config" % "0.4.1"
)
```

Step: 2

Sample input JSON file:

```
{
    "id": "0001",
    "address" : {
        "country": {
            "state":{
                "city":{
                    "locality": "some_place"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters":
        {
            "batter":
                [
                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                    { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                    { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                ]
        },
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
            { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
            { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
            { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
            { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
        ]
}
```

Step: 3

JSON File Reading code:

```
    sealed trait FileRead [T, R] extends (T => R) with Serializable

    object FileRead {

      implicit object FileReadImpl extends FileRead[String, String] {
        override def apply(inputSource: String): String = {
          val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile(inputSource)
          try source.mkString finally source.close()
       }
      }
    }
```

Step: 4

JSON to Config file conversion code:

```
import io.circe.Json
import io.circe.config.{parser, printer}

sealed trait JsonToConfig[T, R] extends (T => R) with Serializable

object JsonToConfig {

  implicit object JsonToConfigImpl extends JsonToConfig[String, String] {
    override def apply(input: String): String = {

      val options = printer.DefaultOptions.setFormatted(false)
      val jsonFormatInput = parser.parse(input).right.get
      val inputJson = Json.fromJsonObject(jsonFormatInput.asObject.get)

      printer.print(inputJson, options)
    }
  }
}
```

Step 5:

Execute the program:

```
object ConversionRun {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val file = "sample.json"

    import FileRead._
    import JsonToConfig._
    val fileRead = implicitly[FileRead[String, String]]
    val convert = implicitly[JsonToConfig[String, String]]

    val out = convert(fileRead(file))

    println(out)
  }
}
```

Output:

```
address{country{state{city{locality="some_place"}}}},batters{batter=[{id="1001",type=Regular},{id="1002",type=Chocolate},{id="1003",type=Blueberry},{id="1004",type="Devil's Food"}]},id="0001",name=Cake,ppu=0.55,topping=[{id="5001",type=None},{id="5002",type=Glazed},{id="5005",type=Sugar},{id="5007",type="Powdered Sugar"},{id="5006",type="Chocolate with Sprinkles"},{id="5003",type=Chocolate},{id="5004",type=Maple}],type=donut
```